# Additional Javascript code to make div visible when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need to know what code to add in order to make the div with id "image1" remain visible when checkbox with id "chk1" is checked and then hidden when unchecked. the checkbox code should override the hover show/hide code. And same for the rest of the checkboxes (chk2 with image2, etc.). Eventually, I'll have 25+ checkboxes...

```js
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image").length;

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
  var optionName = 'option' + i;
  var imageName = 'image' + i;
  (function(optionName, imageName) {
    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = function() {
      document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
    }

    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = function() {
      document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
    }
  })(optionName, imageName);
}
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
<div class="product-option"><span id="option1">[checkbox checkbox-600 use_label_element "Envoy Elite" id="chk1"]</span></div>
<div class="product-option"><span id="option2">[checkbox checkbox-601 use_label_element "Envoy Echo" id="chk2"]</span></div><br>
<div class="product-option"><span id="option3">[checkbox checkbox-602 use_label_element "Envoy Equip" id="chk3"]</span></div>
<div class="product-option"><span id="option4">[checkbox checkbox-603 use_label_element "Envoy Ember" id="chk4"]</span></div>
</div>
<div class="product-image-container">
<div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
<div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
<div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
<div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **checkbox code should override the hover show/hide code** ? do you need hover event or not ? If yes then how it behave when you checked the checkbox ?

Comment: I want the image to appear when you hover over the checkbox and label but disappear when you stop hovering. I want it to appear when the checkbox is checked, and remain visible even if mouse isn't hovering over the checkbox and label. It will only disappear if it is unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below,

I have added new attribute to your image tag and called on function on click on check box,

Temporary I have just change the image width to 10% so you can see the effect.

```js
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image").length;

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
  var optionName = 'option' + i;
  var imageName = 'image' + i;
  (function(optionName, imageName) {
    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = function() {
   if(!document.getElementById(optionName).children[0].checked){
  document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
   }
    }

    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = function() {
   if(!document.getElementById(optionName).children[0].checked){
  document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
   }
    }
  })(optionName, imageName);
  
}

function showImage(){
 var ele = document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("data-img"));
 if(event.target.checked){
  ele.style.display='block';
 }else{
  ele.style.display='none';
 }
 
}
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-image {
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
<div class="product-option"><span id="option1"><input type="checkbox" class="imageChk"  onclick="showImage();" id="chk1" data-img="image1"/>Image1</span></div>
<div class="product-option"><span id="option2"><input type="checkbox" class="imageChk"  onclick="showImage();" id="chk2" data-img="image2"/>Image2</span></div><br>
<div class="product-option"><span id="option3"><input type="checkbox" class="imageChk"  onclick="showImage();" id="chk3" data-img="image3"/>Image3</span></div>
<div class="product-option"><span id="option4"><input type="checkbox" class="imageChk"  onclick="showImage();" id="chk4" data-img="image4"/>Image4</span></div>
</div>
<div class="product-image-container">
<div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Elite-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
<div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Echo-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
<div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Equip-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
<div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="https://megavoice.com/uploads/MegaVoice-Audio-Bible-Envoy-Ember-Solar-Powered.png"></div>
</div>
```